# Adding Confidence Interval to ANOVA Main Effect & Interaction Plots

Tags: stat, anova, confidence-interval, minitab

In Minitab, Stat > ANOVA > Main Effects Plot or Interactions Plot
Is there a way to add confidence interval to the main effect and interaction plots?

I would like to have a simple and quick view to show that if the main effect or interaction is significant through the confidence interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO, It is not possible to add confidence interval to the Main/Interaction plots in any version of Minitab using either Menu based navigation or command.